# Find locations of all matches in a range

Tags: excel

I would like to list the lines where there is a `FAIL` written.
As it sounds very simple in VBA it seems fairly complicated to integrate that in a cell formula.

So I wanted to know if there was a simple way of listing all thoses matches.

I have tried this `=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF(Y23:Z90="FAIL";1;""))` just to try a function I saw on internet but it gives me `#value!` error and I don't know why.

I then wanted to do something like `=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF(Y23:Z90="FAIL";ROW(Y23:Z90);""))` but I'm guessing this would definitely not work.

I [saw](https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/) that we could do it with `index` and `aggregate` but it seems really too complicated for such a simple problem. However if this is the only solution I will take a more serious look at it.

Does anyone has a better way to do what I want to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The formula you're using should be entered as an [array formula](https://www.vertex42.com/blog/excel-formulas/array-formula-examples.html). Edit the cell that has the formula and "enter" it as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @PeterT Thank you! I will correct that

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Peter, I solved my problem and `{=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF(Y23:Z90="FAIL";ROW(Y23:Z90);""))}` works and gives me a list of the lines.